# How to change Django crispy forms login error?

Tags: python, django, authentication

How can I change the error that Django crispy forms display when a user fails to enter a username and password?

This is the image that currently appears to me when I go to make a wrong login, I would like to replace the internal writing and also, I would like to center it

[This is my login view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSpfw.png)

This is forms.py file:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import MyUser

######### FORM PER LA REGISTRAZIONE DELL'UTENTE FINALE #########
class FormRegistrazione(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label="Nome Utente", required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Pablitos123', 'class': 'text-left'}))
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label="Nome", required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Mario', 'class': 'text-left'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label="Cognome", required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Rossi', 'class': 'text-left'}))
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=True, widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'esempio@esempio.it', 'class': 'text-left'}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Inserisci la tua password', 'class': 'text-left'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Inserisci nuovamente la tua password', 'class': 'text-left'}))
    indirizzo = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Via/Piazza Roma, 25', 'class': 'text-left'}))
    citta = forms.CharField(max_length=50, label="Città", required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Roma', 'class': 'text-left'}))
    CAP = forms.CharField(max_length=5, label="CAP", required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': '56123', 'class': 'text-left'}))

    ######### FUNZIONE PER CANCELLARE GLI help_text DAL FORM #########
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FormRegistrazione, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


        for fieldname in ['username', 'password1', 'password2']:
            self.fields[fieldname].help_text = None

    ######### CAMPI DEL FORM CON MODELLO DEL DB #########
    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'indirizzo', 'citta', 'CAP',]
```

This is views.py file:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from .models import MyUser
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponseRedirect, render

from accounts.forms import FormRegistrazione

# Create your views here.

######### RESTITUISCO LA HOMEPAGE #########
def home(request):
    return render(request, "base.html")

######### RESTITUISCO UNA PAGINA DI PROVA #########
def feat(request):
    return render(request, "feat.html")


######### RESTITUISCO LA PAGINA DELLA REGISTRAZIONE #########
def registrazione_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = FormRegistrazione(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data["username"]
            email = form.cleaned_data["email"]
            password = form.cleaned_data["password1"]
            first_name = form.cleaned_data["first_name"]
            last_name = form.cleaned_data["last_name"]
            indirizzo = form.cleaned_data["indirizzo"]
            citta = form.cleaned_data["citta"]
            CAP = form.cleaned_data["CAP"]
            user = MyUser.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password, email=email, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, indirizzo=indirizzo, citta=citta, CAP=CAP)
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
    else:
        form = FormRegistrazione()
    context = {"form": form}
    return render(request, 'registration/registrazione.html', context)
```

This is my login page:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block head_title %}{{ block.super }} - Login{% endblock head_title %}

{% block content %}

    <div class="row justify-content-center mt-6">
        <div class="col-4 text-center">
            <h2>Accedi</h2>
            {% if form.errors %}
              <p>username or password not correct</p>
            {% endif %}
            <form class="" action="{% url 'login' %}" method="POST" novalidate>
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form|crispy }}
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Login">
                <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">
            </form>
            <br>
            <p><a href="{% url 'password_reset' %}">Password dimenticata?</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock content %}
```